# How to make the component affiliate tracker responsive?

Tags: templates, joomla, frameworks

I have a Joomla 3.8 website. I have installed Joomla Affiliate Tracker
and the template is PURITY III 1.2.3.

All my pages of all my components are responsive and fine.

I have an issue with a Joomla component (or the template); pages of this component are not responsive.

In this screenshot you can see that is not responsive, and you can see the code creating this issue.

[image]

So I read the doc http://www.t3-framework.org/documentation/bs3-layout-system
http://www.t3-framework.org/documentation/customization

I searched for similar issues on the web, but I couldn’t find where to change these t3-content col-xs-12.

So I download all website pages by ftp and made a search for this specific string “t3-content  col-xs-12”

I couldn’t find it. I found where you define the width of col-s, col-xs, col-m, etc… but I am afraid to destroy all the template because of this unique component. I suspect more an issue with the component.

I made some tests:

1. I assigned an article to this same menu and the page was responsive.
2. I tested component on default template protostar and the component was responsive.

[image]

My conclusion is there is an incompatibility with PURITY III T3 System. But I maybe wrong. I am not programmer and it is very hard for me to fix that.

I contacted of Joomla Affiliate Tracker support and waiting for answer. As it is not mainly the fault of component, I am not sure to get help.

Comment: For all of your Joomla support questions, I recommend [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.